# asp:RadioButton or asp:RadioButtonList

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm looking for an informed opinion on which way I should take a solution for a client.

The solution involves using radio buttons inside an asp:Repeater. Originally I opted to use an asp:RadioButtonList but the issue I have run into is it insists on providing a text label, when using a DataSourceID and I cannot envelop the radiobutton tag with the label tag thus preventing me from providing a greater click area for anyone using touch screen devices.

It renders like this:

```
<td>
  <input />
  <label />
</td>
```

What I want is:

```
<td>
  <label>
    <input />
  </label>
</td>
```

I can achieve the above using by wrapping an asp:RadioButton in a label tag. But then finding out which radiobutton within the GroupName has been selected means I need to go through each radiobutton and check its checked property. Not very elegant.

I have done some research on the topic, and it looks like I could use CSS to move the asp:RadioButtonList radiobuttons position so it looks like they are contained with in the label and to remove the label text.

Removing the DataSourceID from the asp:RadioButtonList removes the `<label>` tag completely. So I could insert a label tag around each radiobutton.

Or just go for the simple approach, drop the asp:RadioButtonList and a iterate through each asp:RadioButton until I find the checked radiobutton.

All of my 'ideas' seem overly complex and not particularly elegant. Has anyone had any experience with similar issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using RadioButtons, using the following code.

```
<td>
  <label>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rb1" runat="server" />
  </label>
</td>
<td>
  <label>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rb2" runat="server" />
  </label>
</td>
<td>
  <label>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rb3" runat="server" />
  </label>
</td>
```

As I stated in the original question the radiobuttons are contained within an asp:Repeater. To iterate through the radiobuttons and each table row I used the following code:

```
For Each item As RepeaterItem In RepeaterName.Items

  If item.ItemType <> ListItemType.Header And item.ItemType <> ListItemType.Footer And item.ItemType <> ListItemType.Separator Then

  Dim listOfNames() As String = {"rb1", "rb2", "rb3"}  
  Dim attended As Boolean = False
  Dim index As Integer = 0

  Do While checked = False

    Dim rbAttendanceCode As RadioButton = CType(item.FindControl(listOfNames(index).ToString), RadioButton)

    If rbAttendanceCode.Checked Then

        'Do whatever you want with the checked radiobutton    
        'set the flag as true so we stop looping through the radio buttons.
        checked = True

      End If

      index += 1

    Loop
  End If
Next
```

Hope people find this useful.